# What does the npx command install?

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

This question is about understanding how the `npx` command works and what it exactly does under the hood. (The documentation does not really help - see below)

From the documentation:

> Installation-less command execution
>
> There is another great feature of npx, which is allowing to run
> commands without first installing them.

Great. Let's try running some command without installation:

`npx node@6 -v`

And in result one gets:

```
Need to install the following packages:
  node@6
Ok to proceed? (y)
```

So there is anyway installation going on. And one could see that something gets installed with `npm cache ls`.

If we run the command `npx node@6 -v` again, there won't be a prompt asking for installation. That means the installation (that didn't happen in the first place) persists. And now one could execute the command even without connection to the internet/npm.

For a person who does not know all nuts and bolts of the npm it is kind of strange to find "installation-less execution", which asks for installation.

Could some one give more logical explanation like: when you execute `npx node@6 -v` this and that happens under the hood, this package will be downloaded and unpacked there ... then executed ... then deleted/or persists for so long ... and so on.

What if I run `npx package` today (and it gets "installed") and I run the command in 3 months? Would `npx` check if there is a newer version or would it call the "installed" one?
Is there a documentation on that?